# call a function from another function increment the number of times for number entered then place an ' !' to every output that is even

Tags: javascript, input, output

I am trying to create a loop.   so far I can get it to say Hello Tom and just the number. I want to add on a function named addOrderListItems that receives the name and numOfTimes as parameters. Then call the addOrderListItems function from the displayHello function and if the number is even add an !
so if I type name Braden and  numOfTimes 8
the output will display a list
1.Hello Braden
2.Hello Braden!
3.Hello Braden
4.Hello Braden!
5.Hello Braden
6.Hello Braden!
7.Hello Braden
8.Hello Braden!
9.Hello Braden

```
function displayHello() {
  let name = document.getElementById("helloNameInput").value,
   numOfTimes = document.getElementById("numOfTimesInput").value;

 
}
    function addOrderListItems() {
    let numOfTimes = 0;
    while (numOfTimes > 0 ) {
    document.getElementById("helloNameOutput").innerHTML = "Hello " + name + numOfTimes;
      numOfTimes++;
    }
  
}

function clearName() {
  document.getElementById("helloNameInput").value = "";
  document.getElementById("numOfTimesInput").value = "";
  document.getElementById("helloNameOutput").innerText = "";
}
```

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>JavaScript: Looping Structures Assignment</title>

    <link href="/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body class="p-3">
    <h1>JavaScript: Looping Structures Assignment</h1>

    <!--Name input-->
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="helloNameInput" class="form-label">Name:</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        name="helloNameInput"
        id="helloNameInput"
        placeholder="Enter a name"
      />
    </div>

    <!--Number of Times input-->
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="numOfTimesInput" class="form-label">Number of Times:</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        name="numOfTimesInput"
        id="numOfTimesInput"
        placeholder="Enter number"
      />
    </div>

    <!--Name output-->
    
    <ol id="helloNameOutput"></ol>
    

    <!--Display Hello! & Reset buttons-->
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="displayHelloButton" onclick="displayHello();"  >
        Display Hello!
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" id="clearButton" onclick=" clearName();">Clear</button>
    </div>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
        ```
````

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I am trying to create a loop.   so far I can get it to say Hello Tom and just the number. I want to add on  a function named addOrderListItems that receives the name and numOfTimes as parameters. Then call the addOrderListItems function from the displayHello function and if the number is even add an !   so if I type Braden B and 8 the output will display a list  1. Hello Braden 2. Hello Braden! 3. Hello Braden 4. Hello Braden! 5. Hello Braden 6. Hello .Braden! 7. Hello Braden 8. Hello Braden! 9. Hello Braden

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need a few functions to help you accomplish your goal and keep your code organized. Below I've created an example in a code snippet to demonstrate how the functionality you described can be implemented. I've included lots of comments to explain and help you understand the steps involved.

You can search on MDN and read the JavaScript documentation if there are parts you've never seen or don't yet understand — for example, here are a few links to some of the DOM APIs used:

- [`Document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [`Element.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove)
- [`Node.firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild)
- [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Keep learning, and good luck in your programming!

```js
const nameInput = document.getElementById('helloNameInput');
const qtyInput = document.getElementById('numOfTimesInput');
const btn = document.getElementById('writeGreeting');
const output = document.getElementById('helloNameOutput');

function createGreetingText (name, withExclamationPoint) {
  return `Hello ${name}${withExclamationPoint ? '!' : ''}`;
}

function createGreetingListItem (name, withExclamationPoint) {
  const listItem = document.createElement('li');
  listItem.textContent = createGreetingText(name, withExclamationPoint);
  return listItem;
}

function clearOutput () {
  // Delete every child element from the output element:
  while (output.firstChild) {
    output.firstChild.remove();
  }
}

function writeGreeting () {
  // Get the trimmed input value (or use "world" if it's empty):
  const name = nameInput.value.trim() || 'world';
  
  // Get the number of times (quantity) from the other input:
  let qty = parseInt(qtyInput.value);

  // If the number input value couldn't be parsed as a valid integer,
  // use 1 as the default valid value and update the input:
  if (!Number.isInteger(qty)) {
    qty = 1;
    qtyInput.value = 1;
  }

  clearOutput();

  // Loop the number of times:
  for (let i = 1; i <= qty; i += 1) {
    // Create and append a list item element each time:
    const isEven = i % 2 === 0;
    const listItem = createGreetingListItem(name, isEven);
    output.appendChild(listItem);
  }
}

// Bind the "writeGreeting" function to the button's "click" event,
// so that it runs each time the button is clicked:
btn.addEventListener('click', writeGreeting);
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 1rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

button, input {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input
    type="text"
    id="helloNameInput"
    placeholder="name"
    value="Braden"
  />
  <input
    type="number"
    step="1"
    min="1"
    id="numOfTimesInput"
    placeholder="# of times"
    value="8"
  />
  <button id="writeGreeting">Write greeting</button>
  <ol id="helloNameOutput"></ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I only get some of what you said, Everything is confusing.